# Line Item displays sku in title

Tags: commerce

How do you hide the SKU in the line item display.

[image: Order]

It seems to be part of the "Line item label" field on
admin/commerce/config/line-items/product/fields
[image: Fields]

Theres also no option in the view to change it.

[image: View Display]

Comment: Neither my line item title nor my line item Labels have the SKU at the end of them, so it's nothing to do with either of these fields. Unless you've manually entered your SKU as the title. Can you give us any more information on your specific setup, is this the only situation that this field behaves like this? do you have any contrib modules that may be altering the carts output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further inspection, I found in the view that "Rewrite the output of this field" was on to include the sku.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the 'Commerce Line Item:Label' field that was appending SKU to the end of title. I excluded it from display & SKU disappeared.

Hope this helps someone.

Regards,

Supriya Rajgopal